# How to compute weighted centroids in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, centroids

I have a group of points and each point has an associated count value. How can I  calculate the centroid of the group weighted by the values associated to each point?

Comment: Is there anything in this article that is of assistance? http://boundlessgeo.com/2014/10/postgis-training-creating-overlays/?utm_source=feedly&utm_reader=feedly&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=postgis-training-creating-overlays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832771/find-the-centroid-of-a-polygon-with-weighted-vertices) that gives a mathematical, but not a Postgres answer. Translating to Postgres/Postgis, you could try something like this:

```
select sum(st_x(pt)*weight)/sum(weight) as cx from weighted_points;
select sum(st_y(pt)*weight)/sum(weight) as cy from weighted_points;
```

Or if you want a point back, then,

```
select st_makepoint(x.cx, y.cy) from 
(select sum(st_x(pt)*weight)/sum(weight) as cx from weighted_points) x,
(select sum(st_y(pt)*weight)/sum(weight) as cy from weighted_points) y
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Fréchet Mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_mean) as a basis for this, you could try something like the following

```
SELECT EXP(SUM(LN(X)*W)/SUM(W)) weightedMedianX,
    EXP(SUM(LN(Y)*W)/SUM(W)) weightedMedianY,
    EXP(SUM(LN(X))/COUNT(*)) medianX,
    EXP(SUM(LN(Y))/COUNT(*)) medianY
FROM PointTable
```